# How to get all paginated data using guzzle promise

Tags: php, promise, guzzle

I am using guzzle for getting post of a single page and it is working fine. But now the problem is page has pagination 20 post on each page. i want to get all the posts. How can I do it by using guzzle ?

here is my code:

```
  public function __construct()
    {
        $this->client = new Client([
            'base_uri' => 'https://xxxxxx.com/',
            'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
        ]);

    }
    public function post($post)
    {
        $response = $this->client->request('GET', $post);

        $output = $response->getBody()->getContents();
        $data = $this->getData($output);
        return $data;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do it in general. HTTP as a protocol doesn't specify anything about pagination. So depends on the server you work with. Usually the response contains something like

```
{
    "page": 5,
    "total": 631
}
```

Based on this info you can create an URL for the next page by adding `?page=6` (also depends on the server) and request it.